# ZTE MF190 3G Modem not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, mobile-broadband

I'm already searching and searching for ways to connect to internet via ZTE broadband stick but I can't find the right solution.

I already used usb-modeswitch, sakis3g and ubuntu's built-in mobile broadband manager but still no luck. Can anyone help me? Thanks!